# How can I find the max values of a list in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, max

I am a Python beginner and have made the following 2 lists:

```
temp = [83, 384, 324.6, -234, -65, -65.838, 23, -85, -73.543, 12.345]
time = [0.0, 3.345, 4.785, 5.31, 6.67, 9.37, 10.54, 11.36, 12.554, 13.445]
```

I am playing a volcano simulator and was able to record the temperatures at certain points in the volcano. I placed these temperatures into a list and also recorded the times in a list. I am attempting to find all the positive values of the list of temperatures.
----- Output I want:

```
newtemp = [83, 384, 324.6, 23, 12.345]
```

Comment: is there anything you have tried, that you could show here

Comment: Welcome to SO, we're here to help you if you have problems with your code, but not to write your code for you - please share what you've tried and what you are having trouble with.

Comment: Hi, rather than using 2 lists, use a list of objects. Something like this: [{temp:384, time:3.3},{temp:324, time:4,7}, ...]

Comment: @Grismar I updated the question. I just am lost on how to find the positive values of the list like I mentioned in the Edit. I am sure you were stuck like this at one point when you started coding.

Comment: @abimbo--it's misleading to use the term local maximum when all you want are the positive values.  Local maximum means the temperature should be larger than its immediate neighbors.  Mentioning local maximums has lead several responders awry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to combine the data points of both list into tuples, 
use a generator expression to get all positive data points from the list of 2-tuples,
use [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to seperate the splatted tuple of 2-tuples back into tuples and use map with list to get lists from it:

```
temp = [83, 384, 324.6, -234, -65, -65.838, 23, -85, -73.543, 12.345]
time = [0.0, 3.345, 4.785, 5.31, 6.67, 9.37, 10.54, 11.36, 12.554, 13.445]

p_temp, p_time = map(list,zip( *(a for a in zip(temp,time) if a[0]>0) ))

print(p_temp)
print(p_time)
```

Output:

```
[83, 384, 324.6, 23, 12.345]
[0.0, 3.345, 4.785, 10.54, 13.445]
```

You can find explanations for `zip()`, `map()` and `list()` here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html

---

The operations step wise transform your data kindof like so:

```
tmp1 = list(zip(temp,time))
tmp2 = list((a for a in tmp1 if a[0]>0))
tmp3 = list(zip( *tmp2 ))
print(tmp1)
print(tmp2)
print(tmp3)
print(*tmp3)
```

Output:

```
# list(zip(temp,time))
[(83, 0.0), (384, 3.345), (324.6, 4.785), (-234, 5.31), (-65, 6.67), (-65.838, 9.37),
 (23, 10.54), (-85, 11.36), (-73.543, 12.554), (12.345, 13.445)]

# list((a for a in tmp1 if a[0]>0))
[(83, 0.0), (384, 3.345), (324.6, 4.785), (23, 10.54), (12.345, 13.445)] 

# list(zip( *tmp2 ))
[(83, 384, 324.6, 23, 12.345), (0.0, 3.345, 4.785, 10.54, 13.445)]

# *list(zip( *tmp2 ))
(83, 384, 324.6, 23, 12.345)  (0.0, 3.345, 4.785, 10.54, 13.445)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is something like this:

```
temp = [83, 384, 324.6, -234, -65, -65.838, 23, -85, -73.543, 12.345]
time = [0.0, 3.345, 4.785, 5.31, 6.67, 9.37, 10.54, 11.36, 12.554, 13.445]

max_temp = max(temp)
max_temp_position = temp.index(max_temp)
max_temp_time = time[max_temp_position]

print(max_temp, max_temp_time )
```

This can be made much easier and better if you use list of dictionaries rather than 2 lists as I mentioned in the comments above.

```
[
  {temp:384, time:3.3},
  {temp:324, time:4,7}, 
  ...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
well if you want the Local Maximas then the  order of temp matters, not the sign,but I'll assume its for the positive local maximas only in the following example

Ex1:

```
def timeToLocalMax(time,temp):
    ans=[]
    for i in range(1,len(temp)-1):
      if temp[i]>temp[i+1] and temp[i]>temp[i-1] and temp[i]>0:
        ans.append((temp[i],time[i])) # you don't have to add both, you can do either also
        #like so ans.append(temp[i]) or ans.append(time[i])
    print(ans)
time=[0.0, 3.345, 4.785, 5.31, 6.67, 9.37, 10.54, 11.36, 12.554, 13.445]
temp=[83, 384, 324.6, -234, -65, -65.838, 23, -85, -73.543, 12.345]
timeToLocalMax(time,temp)
```

output:

```
[(384, 3.345), (23, 10.54)]
```

or

```
[384, 23]
```

Ex2:
otherwise, if you just want the positive value of temp you can do this

```
ans=[i for i in temp if i>0]
```

then, if you want the times corresponding to the positive values, you'd do this

```
ans=[time[i] for i in range(len(temp)) if temp[i]>0]
```

or if you want both you'd do this

```
ans=[(time[i],temp[i]) for i in range(len(temp)) if temp[i]>0]
```